# Second pthread won't enter second loop

Tags: c, pthreads, max

I'm facing a problem with my threads. I'm trying to find the max element of the main diagonal in a 2-dimensional array. The first pthread will do its thing and find the max element. But, when the second and thrird and so on array "joins the party" they will not enter the second while. My function looks like this:

```
void* findMax() {
    //int t = 1;

    //*arr.times = 0;

    for (*arr.countI = 0; *arr.countI < *arr.l; (*arr.countI)++) {
        for (*arr.countJ = 0; *arr.countJ < *arr.l; (*arr.countJ)++) {
            printf("%d ", arr.a[*arr.countI][*arr.countJ]);
            if (*arr.l - *arr.countJ == 1)
                printf("\n");
        }
    }

    *arr.countI = 0;
    *arr.countJ = 0;

    while (*arr.countI != *arr.l) {
        while (*arr.countJ != *arr.l) {
            if (*arr.countI == *arr.countJ) {
                if (abs(arr.a[*arr.countI][*arr.countJ]) > *arr.max)
                    *arr.max = abs(arr.a[*arr.countI][*arr.countJ]);
            }

            ++(*arr.countJ);
        }

        ++(*arr.countI);

        /*if (++(*arr.times) == 1) {
            *arr.times = 0;
            break;
        }*/
    }

    printf("max = %d\n", *arr.max);
}
```

So if I enter this array

```
 4 1 1
 1 6 1
 1 1 3
```

the max will equal 4 which is not right of course.

`arr` is a struct (global) that has everything I need; `arr.a` is the array.

I have messed with it a lot over the last couple of days but with no luck...

Comment: All those `*arr.countI` etc references are ugly. Where is the mutual exclusion that makes sure that no thread is modifying anything inside `arr` while another thread is also modifying it? You have `*arr.countI = 0;` for example, but no visible mutual exclusion. You have `*arr.max = abs(arr.a[*arr.countI][*arr.countJ]);` and no mutual exclusion. You have `++(*arr.countJ);` and no mutual exclusion. None of the threads has the first clue about what's going on. Maybe you're lucky and `*arr.countI == *arr.l` so they don't enter the loop. But you've no concurrency control so everything is guesswork.

Comment: I think you should stop using `countI` and `countJ` from the global data, and also `arr.max` most of the time. Those should be replaced by per-thread local variables (`int i; int j; int max;`). If you're scanning down the main diagonal, you don't need nested loops — you can simply step down the diagonal. Your code is very complex for a very simple job. You still need a mutex to allow `*arr.max` to be set reliably.  `arr.a` and `*arr.l` are 'OK' (why is `*arr.l` a pointer?) because you don't modify those. You promise to return a `void *` and return nothing. Lying to your compiler is a Bad Idea.

Comment: And if this function is called by `pthread_create()`, it is missing its input argument.  The thread function is passed a `void *` argument, which it may or may not really use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously noted in comments, you have no mutual exclusion, so your threads are all busily manipulating elements of the global array without regard to what other threads are doing.

> All those `*arr.countI` etc references are ugly. Where is the mutual exclusion that makes sure that no thread is modifying anything inside `arr` while another thread is also modifying it? You have `*arr.countI = 0;`, for example, but no visible mutual exclusion. You have `*arr.max = abs(arr.a[*arr.countI][*arr.countJ]);` and no mutual exclusion. You have `++(*arr.countJ);` and no mutual exclusion. None of the threads has the first clue about what's going on. Maybe you're lucky and `*arr.countI == *arr.l` so they don't enter the loop. But you've no concurrency control so everything is guesswork.
>
> I think you should stop using `countI` and `countJ` from the global data, and also `arr.max` most of the time. Those should be replaced by per-thread local variables (`int i; int j; int max;`). If you're scanning down the main diagonal, you don't need nested loops — you can simply step down the diagonal. Your code is very complex for a very simple job. You still need a mutex to allow `*arr.max` to be set reliably. `arr.a` and `*arr.l` are 'OK' (but why is `*arr.l` a pointer?) because you don't modify those. You promise to return a `void *` and return nothing. Lying to your compiler is a Bad Idea™.

If your threads store anything into your global structure (`arr`), you need to make sure there is mutual exclusion in place.  I assume you have or add a member `mtx` which is a pointer to a `pthread_mutex_t` that is initialized before the thread functions are invoked.  I'm also assuming your `findMax()` function is called from `pthread_create()` (and passed to it as a function pointer).

You could use much simpler code for the task, like this:

```
void *findMax(void *arg)
{
    assert(arg == 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < *arr.l; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *arr.l; j++) {
            printf("%d ", arr.a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    int max = abs(arr.a[0][0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < *arr.l; i++)
    {
        int absval = abs(arr.a[i][i]);
        if (absval > max)
            max = absval;
    }

    if (pthread_mutex_lock(arr.mtx) == 0)
    {
        *arr.max = max;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(arr.mtx);
    }

    printf("max = %d\n", *arr.max);
    return 0;
}
```

<sup>*Warning: uncompiled code!*</sup>